# After downloading Ubuntu can I still access my Windows 10 files and photos/

Tags: dual-boot

I have windows 10 on my Dell Inspiron 15 laptop series 5000 with i7 processor and I want to download Ubuntu 16.4. If I do this will I still be able to access my windows 10 files and photos?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will be able to access the Windows files in Ubutnu as a regular file system. Dual boot will not have any affect on your personal files.